How can I clear/dispose Shared Preferences when logging out of a Flutter app?
Sorry my bad English in advance.
I would like to find out how I can clear SharedPreferences when I log out of the application. In my case, the Logout button is on screen 1 (HomePage).
On screen 2, I'm keeping items in a list that generates a Listview with several tiles. When I leave screen 2 to go to another screen, the list items must be kept so that the listview is displayed.This part kinda works.
However, when I log out of the application and log into another account, items from the account I was previously logged into appear. I am aware of the existence of .clear() but I don't know how it would be implemented given that the list is on one screen and the logout button on another.

I've tried to use clear on the HomePage screen but it didn't work.
Tried to create an abstract class involving SharedPreferences but turns out I am not that skillful at managing classes.


when you are calling logout function after that call .clear() function on sharedpreferences.

considering you are just storing id of the user from api and clearing it after logging out.
use shared preference
set data
// Obtain shared preferences.
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

// Save an String value to 'action' key.
await prefs.setString('userName', 'abcd1');

delete data
await prefs.remove('userName');

